# Use custom labeling function for labeling y axis in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to create a custom function for making labels within `ggplot`. For example, I can use `labels = scales::percent` within `scale_y_continuous()` to format the y axis using percentage sign. However, I would like more control over the labeling function.

```
> mydf <- data.frame(a = 1:9,
+                    b = 1:9 / 10)
> mydf
  a   b
1 1 0.1
2 2 0.2
3 3 0.3
4 4 0.4
5 5 0.5
6 6 0.6
7 7 0.7
8 8 0.8
9 9 0.9
> ggplot(mydf) + geom_point(aes(x = a, y = b)) + scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)
```

The documentation for `scale_y_continuous()` suggests that it is possible to create a custom function that can take in breaks and output labels, but there is no demonstration of this in the documentation.

> **labels** One of:
>
> ```
> NULL for no labels
>
> waiver() for the default labels computed by the transformation object
>
> A character vector giving labels (must be same length as breaks)
>
> A function that takes the breaks as input and returns labels as output
> ```

Comment: Can you give an example of what you'd want the final labels to look like? From what I remember, you just need to create a function that takes a numeric vector (the "raw" break values), and returns a character vector of the same length.

Comment: @Marius yeah you're right, I was over-thinking it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah, I managed to figure it out. For example, the function below allows me to control the number of decimal places while also converting values into percentages.

```
my_func <- function(x, decimals = 1) {
  fmt <- paste0("%.", decimals, "f") # eg "%.3f"
  num_string <- sprintf(fmt, 100*x)
  final_string <- paste0(num_string, "%")
  return(final_string)
}

ggplot(mydf) + 
  geom_point(aes(x = a, y = b)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels = function(i) my_func(i, decimals = 0))
```

Comment: You can do this with the built-in `scales::percent_format()` function. `labels = percent_format(accuracy = 1)` to round to the nearest 1, `labels = percent_format(accuracy = 0.5)` to round to the nearest 0.5, etc. See the `?percent_format` help page for details and examples.

Comment: This was just a trivial example to demonstrate. I desired more specific formatting for my particular problem (simple way to adjust padding, proportions, rounding, etc).

Answer (score 3):

Like this.

```r
library(tidyverse)

mydf <- data.frame(a = 1:9, b = 1:9 / 10)

mylabels <- function(breaks){
    labels <- sprintf("%i%%", breaks*100) # make your labels here
    return(labels)
}

ggplot(mydf) + 
    geom_point(aes(x = a, y = b)) + 
    scale_y_continuous(labels = mylabels)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-05-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how much customization you need, you might still be able to use the built-in functions. For example, to get percent labels with three decimal places, you could do:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

ggplot(mydf, aes(a, b)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels=percent_format(accuracy=0.001))
```

[image]